# How to enable ambient occlusion with python?

Tags: python, properties

I am trying to access the world shading settings in python.
I want to enable ambient occlusion and give it a value of `0.5`.
I have tried:

```
bpy.types.WorldLighting.use_ambient_occlusion()
```

But I didn't work.

Comment: `types` is only used for documentation. See the api reference. http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_0/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=types#module-bpy.types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To turn Ambient Occlusion on you must set its value to `True`. What you are doing wrong is that you are trying to execute the function `use_ambient_occlusion()` which does not exist because it's variable not a function.

```
import bpy
bpy.context.scene.world.light_settings.use_ambient_occlusion = True  # turn AO on
bpy.context.scene.world.light_settings.ao_factor = 0.5  # set it to 0.5
```